# Does Laravel handle reserved PHP and MySQL words?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, reserved-words

We tend to use the reserved word `name` quite often in our MySQL columns with all Laravel applications. We never had a problem so far.

So I was wondering - does Laravel handle that automatically?

Comment: We've never had any issues using `name` with Laravel and MySQL

Answer (score 1):

There is no problem in using reserved words in MySQL column. In that case eloquent doesn't care about PHP reserved names. Even if your table name coincides with any reserved word then still it shouldn't be any problem.

However, in model or routes, using reserved name can be a bit problem. Suppose, you have a model named 'List'. If you want to get all the List items from database it may cause some problems. For example, the following code will return an error.

```
Route::get('/', function() {
    $lists = List::all();
    dd($lists);
});
```

If there is a table called 'list' then it won't be a problem. But the model name shouldn't be any reserved word.